# Encrypt and Decrypt with Rijndael data too long

Tags: c#, .net, security, aes, rijndael

I'm trying to get this code to encrypt and decrypt but I keep getting data length too long when decrypting during the `.FlushFinalBlock()`.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here because I'm out of my element on this issue.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Encryption is OK, but it cannot decrypt its encryption.

```
   static byte[] u8_Salt = new byte[] { 0x26, 0x19, 0x81, 0x4E, 0xA0, 0x6D, 0x95, 0x34, 0x26, 0x75, 0x64, 0x05, 0xF6 };

   public static string Encrypt(string data, string password)
    {
        //
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, u8_Salt);
        //
        Rijndael i_Alg = Rijndael.Create();
        i_Alg.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
        i_Alg.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        i_Alg.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        //
        using (var cryptoProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider())
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
        {
            writer.Write(data);
            writer.Flush();
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            writer.Flush();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
        }
    }
    public static string Decrypt(string data, string password)
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, u8_Salt);
        //
        Rijndael i_Alg = Rijndael.Create();
        i_Alg.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
        i_Alg.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        i_Alg.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        //
        using (var cryptoProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider())
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, cryptoProvider.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
        {
            writer.Write(data);
            writer.Flush();
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            writer.Flush();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Dude, that is perfect! Loving that extension.. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code. First, you are creating a *Rijndael (AES)* object. However, you're using the `DESCryptoServiceProvider` which means that you are actually using DES, not Rijndael. Because of that you also have the problem that you are not setting the key for the algorithm. Below are your two functions re-written using the `RijndaelManaged` algorithm which is the managed implementation of the `AES` algorithm on .NET.  I've tested and you can encrypt and decrypt with no problem. Also: don't use that salt value, it's all over the internet.

```
static byte[] u8_Salt = new byte[] { 0x26, 0x19, 0x81, 0x4E, 0xA0, 0x6D, 0x95, 0x34, 0x26, 0x75, 0x64, 0x05, 0xF6 };

public static string EncryptString(string plainText, string password)
{
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, u8_Salt);
    using (RijndaelManaged i_Alg = new RijndaelManaged { Key = pdb.GetBytes(32), IV = pdb.GetBytes(16) })
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, i_Alg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

            return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
        }
    }
}

public static string Decrypt(string cipherText, string password)
{
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, u8_Salt);

    using (RijndaelManaged i_Alg = new RijndaelManaged { Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros, Key = pdb.GetBytes(32), IV = pdb.GetBytes(16) })
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, i_Alg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
                cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                cryptoStream.Flush();

                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To generate a random salt I would use the [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.getbytes.aspx)  this will generate a cryptographically secure random byte array that you can use.  You'll need to generate it in a separate process and use it as your salt.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a resource that i shows how to choose correct salt values?

Comment: I've edited the answer to add information about generating a random salt.

Comment: My preference to be honest with you is to just generate a random key with the RNGCryptoServiceProvider and not use the Rfc2898DeriveBytes at all.  I don't think there's a need if you're using a random key.  The only additional thing you'll need to do is check the output against any weak keys that may exist.  Reason is that Rfc2898DeriveBytes will use a Sha-1 HMAC using your password as the key for that, then hash the salt so you may be reducing your key space since Sha-1 outputs 160 bits whereas AES can take up to a 256 bit key.